# Python Requests and strange behaviour of website API: 403 server response

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I write some parser on Python with requests lib. I access to website API (it located on cloudflare) with payload request looks like https://webapi.somesite.com/req?option1=XXX?options2=YYY

So when I try first time I used just `r = requests.get(url)`, I received *<Response [403]>*

Ok, after that on this computer I used header looks like *headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}*.
But I still receive *<Response [403]>*.
When I try to open this webpage (https://webapi.somesite...) using Browser I can open it without any problem. I understand that I can use Selenium to work with it but I don't want to go this way. Especially since I try on another computer (laptop) and use header with `r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)` from the very beginning. And what was my surprise when it works: *<Response [200]>*

Both of computers have the same IP, so I exclude IP ban (besides I can access to webpage using browser without any problem).
I try to access on the very first computer with another virtual environment, using PyCharm, Jupiter Notebook. But everywhere result is the same. On my laptop it's working good all this time.
Also I try to use exact headers value that I see on the Browser devconsole when it communicate with this page. But all of this with was unsuccessful.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and what I should to do in order to defeat this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use session to get the cookie and avoid HTTP403

```
import requests:

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}

# Setup session
s = requests.session(headers=headers)

# First request to initialize session cookie
s.get('https://webapi.somesite.com)

# Now try a real request
s.get('https://webapi.somesite.com/req?option1=XXX?options2=YYY')
```